# Does OCI supports XMLType data without the Oracle XDK

Tags: c, oracle, oracle-call-interface

I'm going to include some XMLType columns in the Oracle database and use the OCI (Oracle C Interface) for read/write data. When I'm referring examples and helps from internet all the examples use XDK for read/write XMLType data?

Is XDK really required for handle XMLType columns from OCI?

I tried to manage these columns as VARCHAR2 columns using OCIBindByName function for inserting data. It worked but cannot insert more than 4k.

OCIBindByName(p_sql, &p_bnd, p_DBCon->p_err, (text *) zName,
        -1, (dvoid *) zValue, iSize, SQLT_STR, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, OCI_DEFAULT);